# Java - How can I get a single pair from a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, key-value, linkedhashmap

Specifically, I want to use a LinkedHashMap in a "for each" loop. For example, let's say I create a LinkedHashMap:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> someHash = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then I fill it with some things:

```
someHash.put("One", new Integer(1));
someHash.put("Two", new Integer(2));
```

Now how might I be able to go through and get each pair? I want something along the lines of:

```
for(<String, Integer> pair : someHash)
{
    //Do stuff.
}
```

But of course this doesn't work. Is there a simple way to retrieve a "pair" object from the hash? Or do I just have to iterate through the length and get the value and key separately? Also, should I really be using a different object if this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Map.Entry` to simulate the `Pair` object that exists in C++.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : someHash.entrySet()) 
{
   System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " Value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Here the `entrySet` is the all key/value pairs from your `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> someHash = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    someHash.put("One", new Integer(1));
    someHash.put("Two", new Integer(2));

    for(String key : someHash.keySet())
    {
         System.out.println("Key : "+key + "  Value : "+someHash.get(key));
    }
```